# JQuery Function .css with clicking action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't the color of the background change of the paragraph?
I've tried using different methods that work, but this one is bothering me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#aod').click(function(){
    $('#para').css('background-color': 'red');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="para"> Obrigado </p>
<a href="#" id="aod">Click on this paragraph.</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is trying to select an element that has not yet been created, if you move that script below the `<a>` it should work

```
<a href="#" id="aod">Click on this paragraph.</a>
<script>
$('#aod').click(function(){
    $('#para').css('background-color': 'red');
});
</script>
```

You can also wrap your code in document.ready so it will be executed after the dom has loaded

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#aod').click(function(){
    $('#para').css('background-color': 'red');
  });
});
</script>
```